# How do I Instantiate Restored View Controllers with Managed Object Context from App Delegate?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, restore

## Problem Statement

In my application, I instantiate a Managed Object Context (moc) in the `applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in my app delegate. During normal operation, I pass that same moc to all view controllers in my hierarchy via custom initWithMoc initialization methods I've set up for each view controller.

Everything works fine, but now I'm trying to use iOS6's built-in state restoration features.

When I get to the `viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` restoration method in the view controller, I'm not sure how to access the newly created moc from the app delegate.

### Question

How do I point each view controller's moc to the same one from the app delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's [iOS App Programming Guide: State Preservation and Restoration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html),

> It is worth noting that if you specify a restoration class for a view
>   controller, UIKit does not try to find your view controller
>   implicitly.

and,

> If you choose to use a restoration class, the implementation of your
>   viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder: method should
>   create a new instance of the class, perform some minimal
>   initialization, and return the resulting object.

you will be able to create instance of child view controller with your legacy `initWithMOC:` method for the *State Preservation and Restoration API* to use.

By doing it this way however you loose the benefit of '**it just works and all you need to do is specify the restoration identifier in your storyboard**'.

Does anyone know a better way? The obvious way is to retrieve it from app delegate, but that is really a non-preferred way of doing it, so please do not recommend that. Besides all evil on a conceptual level, retrieving it from app delegate kills the benefits of using discardable nested contexts.

Comment: Aha. I see, and now that you specifically stated it, I realize that I was again over-thinking everything. I keep disbelieving the "it just works" promise and try to do too much. I took out all my extra, unnecessary work, and it did work as promised. (I got caught in a quagmire of trying to reach back up the VC hierarchy for multiple objects, and that obviously did not work out for me.) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to register your `NSPersistentContainer` subclass or own Core Data stack object (adpopting the UIStateRestoring protocol) via `UIApplication`'s `registerObjectForStateRestoration` and then encode and decode the pointer in the view controller subclass's restoration methods.